# Asterisk auto dial out and play message

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to create a working .call file to dial a phone number and play message using DADHI/g0. According to this page : http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out the minimal call file is:

```
Channel: SIP/trunkname/18882223333
Application: Playback
Data: hello-world
```

So i changed it to this:

```
Channel: DAHDI/g0/***********
Application: Playback
Data: hello-world
```

And this is the error shown at Asterisk CLI:

```
[2015-10-24 21:53:28] WARNING[3148]: pbx_spool.c:309 safe_append: Unable to set utime on /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/hamid.call: Operation not permitted
[2015-10-24 21:53:33] WARNING[6778][C-00000089]: pbx.c:6646 __ast_pbx_run: Channel 'DAHDI/1-1' sent to invalid extension but no invalid handler: context,exten,priority=outgoing,100,1
[2015-10-24 21:53:33] NOTICE[6778]: pbx_spool.c:402 attempt_thread: Call completed to DAHDI/g0/933377136
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of this messages says the call is failed.

`Unable to set utime ...` - hamid.call doesn't belong to a user in which asterisk is started. So just change the owner of hamid.call.

`...sent to invalid extension...` i think this message doesn't belong to this call. Because your call file doesn't send a channel to any extension.

`Call completed to DAHDI/g0/933377136` means the call was successfull.